# VB Saving Listview Items Error

Tags: vb.net, listview, text, save, items

Well the code itself works. The problem occurs when there is a sub items without text, the program will crash. I'm looking for a method that will bypass this annoying error.

My Code:

```
If ComboBox1.Text = "Everything" Then
Dim SetSave As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog
            SetSave.Title = ".txt"
            SetSave.Filter = ".txt File (*.txt)|*.txt"
If SetSave.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
Dim s As New IO.StreamWriter(SetSave.FileName, False)
For Each myItem As ListViewItem In Form1.ListView1.Items
s.WriteLine(myItem.Text & TextBox1.Text &         myItem.SubItems(1).Text & TextBox1.Text &  myItem.SubItems(2).Text & TextBox1.Text &   myItem.SubItems(3).Text & TextBox1.Text &     myItem.SubItems(4).Text & TextBox1.Text &     myItem.SubItems(5).Text & TextBox1.Text & myItem.SubItems(6).Text & TextBox1.Text &     myItem.SubItems(7).Text) '// write Item and SubItem.
Next
s.Close()
End If
```

Error:(this indicates the the listview item without text it can range from number 1 up to 7, the one below is 5)
InvalidArgument=Value of '5' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

Answer (score 1):

Your indexing is starting at 1. VB indexing starts at 0 so for 5 items you whould have index values of 0 to 4